# How to interpret intercept and coefficient with binomial variables in statsmodels Logit

Tags: python, interceptor, statsmodels, coefficients

We trying to assess the chances to sell Personal Loan to the person who has CD Account. So in our database, we have observations with different sets of both variables.

I'm fitting logistic regression with two binomial variables. All is work but I can't understand the meaning of intercept and variable coefficients of its size...

```
log_mod = sm.Logit(bin_df['Personal Loan'], bin_df[['intercept', 'CD Account']]).fit() 

log_mod.summary()
```

This is what i got:

```
              coef  std err     z   P>|z|    [0.025 0.975]
intercept   -2.5508 0.056   -45.301 0.000   -2.661  -2.440
CD Account  2.4049  0.128   18.730  0.000   2.153   2.657
```

The odds for CD Account is:

```
np.exp(log_mod.params[1])
11.076978939724048
```

How to interpret negative intercept?

How to interpret such big odds? What can i say?

Comment: This belongs on stats exchange not stack overflow. This is a site about programming issues, this is a question about interpreting statistical outcomes.

Comment: wrong, man... "This question appears to be off-topic for this site" - that what I got there

Comment: You've been short changed. You wont get an answer here I wouldnt have thought.